# Proving that if $u \in A$ is an upper bound of $A$, then $u = \sup A$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ a nonempty set of real numbers bounded above and $u$ be an upper bound of $A$. Prove that if $u\in A$, then $u=\sup A$.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward; where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you even tried?

Comment: Assume $v$ is an upper bound and $v > u$. Arrive at a contradiction. Conclude it must be $v \leq u$.

Comment: Note that Brian Scott and TMM's comments are meant to help us formulate a response. We believe in helping people learn, but [you should put in some effort to let us better help you](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of supremum: If the non-empty  set of real numbers $S$ is bounded above then $u$ is the supremum of $S$ if both the following hold:

$\ \ \ $1) $u$ is an upper bound of $S$

and

$\ \ \  $2) if $v$ is any upper bound of $S$, then $u\le v$.

A hint for your problem: Suppose $v$ is another upper bound of $A$. Think about condition 2), keeping in mind that $u\in A$.